# Matplotlib - Draw points that satisfy condition

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am new to Matplotlib and am trying to display on a graph all the points that satisfy a condition.
For example I want to draw all the points (x,y) where x - 4 <= y - 5.

But I can't find a way to do this, do I need to generate all those points manually, store them in an array and then use scatter (I think) to display them?

Thanks,
Max

Comment: try [`fill_between`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.fill_between)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you will have to use an array. For the example from "fill_between" it would be:

```
    x = np.arange(0.0, 2, 0.01)
    y = x + 1
    plt.plot(x, y,color='black')
    plt.fill_between(x, y, y2=y.max(), where=y>= x+1, facecolor='green',interpolate=True)
    plt.show()
```